# FFmpeg - Recent vf_drawtext changes causing font render jitter - libharfbuz issue

Tags: ffmpeg, video, fonts

On 2023/06/19 the following commits were made to the ffmpeg drawtext filter:

[avfilter/vf_drawtext: improve glyph shaping and positioning](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/1eeb59a2099479eeead8cdc0d4586443fb301a8a)

[avfilter/vf_drawtext: implement text alignment](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/5f2d907de2ddefd024d161b66d63f8da6208d4d0)

[avfilter/vf_drawtext: use flags type of option for text_align](https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/commit/ea190b8a2385ae527c2539ab63e668d02ca56b00)

ffmpeg builds with these changes produce problematic font rendering results. For example, when rendering running timecode - see below. This is despite using a monospaced font that should not exhibit this issue and, as shown, did not before the above commits.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=black:size=300x100:rate=24" -t 2 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf: fontcolor=white: fontsize=40: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h-th)/2: rate=24: timecode='01\:14\:13\:19'" timecode.mov
```

Before 2023/06/19 drawtext changes (ffmpeg version N-111124-g61047f0f8):

[image: Before 2023/06/19]

After 2023/06/19 drawtext changes (ffmpeg version N-111242-g1bcb8a7338):

[image: After 2023/06/19]

I'm unsure if this is now a question of using the text_align command (for which the documentation isn't very clear) or a bug introduced with the libharfbuz library.

Current ffmpeg build I'm using that shows this issue:

```
ffmpeg version N-111671-gc7ff0c3e4b-https://www.martin-riedl.de Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/ffmpeg_arm64/out --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-version='https://www.martin-riedl.de' --enable-gray --enable-libxml2 --enable-gpl --enable-libfreetype --enable-fontconfig --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libbluray --enable-libsnappy --enable-libvmaf --enable-libass --enable-libklvanc --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-libaom --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora
```

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: The bug seems to be related to `x=(w-tw)/2`. There is no jitter when using `x=20`. You may submit a bug report...

Comment: Bug report submitted
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10531

Comment: This has been fixed